# confused by C syntax

Tags: c, syntax

i'm new at c.. and still having trouble at the syntax, hope you can help me... cause i'm stuck at this code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(void){
     FILE *stream = NULL;
     stream = fopen("studentinfo.txt", "a+");
     /*some of initialization were used for testing purposes only*/

     char arr[5];
     char arr2[5];
     int i;
     char name[3];
     char course[5];

     printf("enter details: ");
     scanf("%s", arr2);

     while(!feof(stream)){ 
        fgets(arr, 100, stream);//i am confused if the line capture was stored at arr[0]
        if(strcmp(arr, arr2)==0){//i want to compare
           printf("success");//testing
        }
        printf("%s", arr);//i wonder does fgets just overwrites the new line to arr[0]
     }

     fclose(stream);

     getch();
}
```

thanks guys...

Comment: Try to format ALL your code as code, it will help us to help you.  And ask specific questions -- all you've told us is that you are still having trouble with the syntax.  That kind of invites the response 'so read one of the many excellent on-line tutorials or books which explain C's syntax'.

Comment: what is the problem ? what you want it to do ? what errors you get ?

Comment: @ muggen: i was actually instructed to do a student information system... and i'm having trouble in editing one of lines... we we're instructed to ask the user for the student id and edit information later... i am thinking to capture first the line and then compare it to the input of the user... hope you can help me... thnx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have an existing file... and your file has data on it. then you could check if the data you typed is existing on the file or not. i'm not sure if this is what you want.

example if you typed... `love` 
and the file also contains the exact word... `love` (on one line)
then it will print "success".

if the data you typed is not existing on the file, it will be appended on the file (on the next line).

```
int main(void){

 char arr[5];
 char arr2[5];
 int i;
 int n=0;

 FILE *stream = NULL;
 FILE *append = NULL;
 stream = fopen("studentinfo.txt", "rt");
 append = fopen("studentinfo.txt", "a+");

 printf("enter details: ");
 scanf("%s", arr2);

 while(!feof(stream)){ 
    fgets(arr, 6, stream);
    if(strcmp(arr, arr2)==0){
       printf("success");
    } else n=-1;  
 }  
 if (n==-1){
     fprintf(append, "%s\n", arr2);
 }
 fclose(stream);
 fclose(append);
 system("pause");
}
```

Comment: thnx a lot newbie... domo arigato :D

Answer (score 6):

1. You're opening studentinfo.txt for appending, but then reading from it (and you don't check the open succeeded
2. you've allocated 5 characters for arr, but read up to 100 characters into it with the fgets. This will overflow and cause memory corruption
3. you've allocated 5 characters for arr2, but read an arbitary number of characters into it - this will overflow and cause memory corruption
4. Fgets reads characters into memory starting at arr. arr[0] is the first character. &arr[0] is the same as arr
5. What's the getch() at the end for?
6. Also, "a+" positions the stream at the end of the file, so you won't be able to read anything.

Comment: 5. probably to stop immediate termination of the program and make it able to see the "success"

Comment: @Muggen. not so sure - it will swallow the newline that the user probably had to enter, though

Comment: `getch` isn't even a standard C function.

Comment: getch(); is used to view the output on the screen when using Dev-C++, else the screen will close very fast... but instead of getch(), system("pause") can be used...

Comment: You'd think these crappy IDEs could be smart enough to at least include a "pause after running program" option to avoid teaching newbies such bad habits...

Answer (score 1):

1. I am not sure why you are opening the stream with a+ because you never actually write to it. Maybe you want to make sure the file exists even if 0 length? You should still check that the open succeeded though.
2. You are then reading 100 characters into an array of just 5 bytes so you will get a serious memory overwrite if the file really does contain that number.
3. The scanf is unsafe too of course as the user may enter too many characters (they are actually limited to 4 because there is a NULL terminator that gets read).
4. At the end you appear to be writing the last line randomly if the user did not enter a matching line from the file.

Comment: hi cashcow... i use a+ because i'v read that it was use for appending a line.. so i was just thinking if... i want to edit a line.. a+ is more suitable than the others coz it was read and write... i am not actually sure about this hope you can help me... thnx